# Generic Data fetch API based on entity name and its primary key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm developing a generic API to fetch data based on the Entity name and its primary key.
URL for get mapping: `api/fetch/{id}/data/{entity}`
There are many entities present like student, course, instructor, class...
Based on the entity name, the API should return data for that entity by given id in URL.
What should be the best approach using spring boot and JPA? 
Trying below, but cannot work when entities are large in number and keep on increasing. Need a generic approach.

```
    @RestController
    public class Datacontroller{
    @Autowired
    CourseRepo courserepo;

    @Autowired
    Studentrepo studentrepo;

    @GetMapping("api/fetch/{id}/data/{entity}")
        public <T> T getData(@PathVariable("id") String id, @PathVariable("entity") String entity) {
            T l = null;
            //depending on entity
            if("course".equals(entity)) {
                Optional<Course> c = courserepo.findById(id);
                l=(T) c.get();
            }

            if("student".equals(entity)) {
                Optional<Student> a = studentrepo.findById(id);
                l = (T) a.get();
            }

            return l;
    }
```

Comment: try `Object` instead of `T`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest). It's a different approach than yours, but it's a Spring project, actively supported and it allows you to directly expose your repositories as REST endpoints.

Comment: I need to fetch data based on entity name. So either there should be way to call respective entity repo dynamically or we should be able to write our own repo interface to accept the entity passed from url.

Answer (score 0):

We can fetch all entities and get entity class from entityName. Once we have class, we can use find method from EntityManager to get the particular record by primary id.

```
public static Class<?> getEntityClass(EntityManager entityManager, String entityName) {
        for (EntityType<?> entity : entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()) {
            if (entityName.equals(entity.getName())) {
                return entity.getJavaType();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```